# Is there a way to make my .bash_profile load the contents of my .profile file?

Tags: macos, bash, .bash-profile

I was using a `.profile` quite happily for two years on my Mac now running Yosemite.

A recent `brew` install created a `.bash_profile` and whilst my `.profile` still exists, it is now no longer loaded.

I could copy and paste everything across, but I'd like to make the minimum number of changes required to solve this problem. I'd like to point the `.profile` file to load the `.bash_profile` file. I'd like to know how.

My question is: **Is there a way to make my `.bash_profile` load the contents of my `.profile` file?**

Comment: In `.bash_profile`, add the line `source ~/.profile`.

Comment: @Larssend Sometimes, a comment with such a simple & short answer elicits a clarification from the OP regarding other requirements that he has but didn't mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this, it's a pretty good article and I think it may be of some use:

https://blog.dghubble.io/post/.bashprofile-.profile-and-.bashrc-conventions/

Comment: Hello. Your link contains the answer, but it is customary to leave a complete answer in the answer itself so that any that comes to superuser at a later time can see the answer directly from the site. This in case the link you provided dies and your answer is left useless. Cheers.

Comment: @Mogget, understood! Thanks for positive feedback.

Answer (score 3):

This is the change I made to my `.bash_profile` file to make this work:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: You don't need to `source` it (you can use `.` instead). Even better is `if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi` where the `-r` tests if `~/.profile` is reabable.